# How to get unchecked checkbox value in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

I am designing an attendance system. on the attendance page, there is roll no., name and present (which is a checkbox). Now what I want to do is if the checkbox is checked it will update attended and total field in my attendance table. and if it is unchecked then it will only update the total field.
I am facing a problem when it is unchecked otherwise it is updating in the table.

**att.jsp**

```
<FORM method="POST" ACTION="test1.jsp">
  <table>
    <% for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){%>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%=results.get(i)%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%=name1.get(i)%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=sports VALUE=<%=results.get(i)%>>
      </td>
      <td>
        Present
      </td>

    </tr>

    <% } %>

  </table>
  <br> <INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

**test1.jsp**

```
      <%! String[] sports; %>
        <% 
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = 
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sis","root","");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();

      sports = request.getParameterValues("sports");
       for (int i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) 
       {
       //out.println(sports[i]);
       }
         //if (sports != null) 
      //{
     for (int i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) 
     {
     if (sports[i] != null) 
    {
       //out.println ("<b> NOT"+sports[i]+"<b>");

     st.executeUpdate("update attendancetb set attended = attended+1, total 
     = total+1 where SID in ('"+sports[i]+"')");
      }

       }
       %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the list of all sports (`results` from the `att.jsp`) to the `test1.jsp` as the session attribute, and then iterate over **all** sports, and use different update statements for the checked case and the unchecked case.

Side notes:

1. Never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.
2. Do not use scriptlets (`<% ... %>`), use [JSTL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm).
3. Do not put business logic and/or SQL code into JSP, use [Model-View-Controller](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) architecture.

Comment: How to pass the list of all sports. Can please explain it by coding?

Comment: In att.jsp `session.setAttribute("ALL_SPORTS", results);`, in test1.jsp `Collection allSports = (Collection) session.getAttribute("ALL_SPORTS");`. See e.g. https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-implicit-object-session-with-examples/ for more info.